# Reading with tn.read in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet, telnetlib

How could I read with tn.read in Python, from the output below, only the "Ont SN" only the thing without what is written in the brackets, so 485754437D85CA9E , "F/S/P" and the "Ont EquipmentID" ?

```
   Number              : 1
   F/S/P               : 0/17/7
   Ont SN              : 485754437D85CA9E (HWTC-7D85CA9E)
   Password            : 0x00000000000000000000
   Loid                : 
   Checkcode           : 
   VendorID            : HWTC
   Ont Version         : 159D.A
   Ont SoftwareVersion : V5R019C00S100
   Ont EquipmentID     : EG8145V5
   Ont autofind time   : 2020-12-15 09:35:48+01:00

   Number              : 2
   F/S/P               : 0/17/7
   Ont SN              : 48575443A9517A9E (HWTC-A9517A9E)
   Password            : 0x00000000000000000000
   Loid                : 
   Checkcode           : 
   VendorID            : HWTC
   Ont Version         : 159D.A
   Ont SoftwareVersion : V5R019C00S100
   Ont EquipmentID     : EG8145V5
   Ont autofind time   : 2020-12-15 08:47:37+01:00
   The number of GPON autofind ONT is 2
```

Summarizing I would need the following data:

```
0/17/7
48575443A9517A9E
EG8145V5

0/17/7
485754437D85CA9E
EG8145V5
```

I tried to do this, and I'm trying to obtain a JSON, but it returns every time the same list with the same object

```
def autofind(ip, user, password):
print('Connecting to OLT {0}'.format(ip))
try:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(ip, 23, 10)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error connecting to OLT, please check the IP address")
    sys.exit()

tn.read_until(b"name:")
tn.write(user.encode('utf-8') + b"\n")
time.sleep(.3)
tn.read_until(b"password:")
tn.write(password.encode('utf-8') + b"\n")
time.sleep(.3)

tn.write(b"enable\n")
time.sleep(.3)

# autofind
tn.write("display ont autofind all ".encode('utf-8') + b"\n")
return_lineid = tn.read_until('The number of GPON'.encode('utf-8'), 3).decode('utf-8')
data_return = return_lineid.splitlines()
records = []
current_record = {}
serials = []
f_s_p = []
passwords = []
autofind_list = []
autofind_object = {}
for line in data_return:
    line = line.strip()

    autofind_list.append(autofind_object)

    if not line:  # empty line
        records.append(current_record)
        current_record = {}
    else:

        if "F/S/P" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            current_record[key] = value
            f_s_p.append(current_record[key])
            autofind_object['F/S/P'] = value
        if "Ont SN" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            current_record[key] = value
            # regex for removing brackets for example (HWTC-7D85CA9E)
            serial = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', value)
            serials.append(serial)
            autofind_object['SN'] = serial
        if "Password" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            if value == '0x00000000000000000000':
                passwords.append(None)
                autofind_object['Password'] = None
                autofind_list.append(autofind_object)
            else:
                passwords.append(current_record[key])
                autofind_object['Password'] = current_record[key]

print("These are the serials number in autofind: ")
print(serials)
print("These are the F/S/P:")
print(f_s_p)
print("These are the passwords:")
print(passwords)
print (autofind_list)
```

output:

```
Connecting to OLT 10.240.0.19
These are the serials number in autofind: 
['485754437D85CA9E ', '48575443A9517A9E ']
These are the F/S/P:
['0/17/7', '0/17/7']
These are the passwords:
[None, None]
[{'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'SN': '48575443A9517A9E ', 'Password': None}, {'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'SN': '48575443A9517A9E ', 'Password': None}]
---
End of the script! 
Time elapsed: 4.27075457572937 seconds
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Not an answer - but a hint - you could start by transforming the lines from telnet into dictionaries, possibly a list of them - 1 list item per record, with each being a dictionary. You can read lines, and split on the colon, using strip to remove the extra whiespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet that should turn those lines into a list of dictionaries:

```
records = []
current_record = {}
for line in data_return:
  line = line.strip()
  if not line: #empty line
    records.append(current_record)
    current_record = {}
  else:
    key, value = line.split(':')
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip()
    current_record[key] = value
```

Not the full answer, but hopefully a helpful hint. You can then process serial afterwards, a list comprehension would be a good way to do that.

Comment: File "autofind_OLT.py", line 50, in autofind
    key, value = line.split(':')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Sounds like the lines between aren't empty. Perhaps try line.strip ()?

Comment: File "autofind_OLT.py", line 50, in autofind
    key, value = line.strip()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: I've edited my suggestion - I meant to suggest you strip the line before it went into the checks and split.

Comment: File "autofind_OLT.py", line 51, in autofind
    key, value = line.split(':')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: I suggest you take it through the debugger, or print each line in loop before splitting it - in quotes, so you can see why the line may be troublesome once stripped.